# Flag Weight as an integer or decimal?

Tags: support, flag-weight

My Flag weight is 4 decimals.  Is this supposed to be this way? I've only ever seen it as an integer.

[image: Flag Weight of 524.2223]

Comment: Flag weight is no longer shown anywhere in the Stack Exchange network.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it approaches 750 (the maximum) it becomes asymptotic, so we show greater precision.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.